# Launching app from email link only works from gmail account

Tags: android

After spending more time on this issue, I found that launching my app from a link within an email DOES in fact work. However, it only works if I set up my android email app with a gmail account. It does not work for the other two accounts: yahoo and work email. So that means, only when I view the email link within my gmail account, I could launch the app. Anyone know what configuration I'm missing or why this is happening?

--- original question below ---

Hi, 
So I was able to get my app to launch from an email link using a custom scheme, however I am only seeing this work while debugging using the emulator. I cannot get it to work when testing on the actual phone/device.
It shows Web page not available The Web page at email:// might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. Is this because the application has not yet been signed? How do I test on my actual phone device.
Thanks

Comment: What is the sdk level of the device vs. the sdk level of the emulator?

Comment: Hi Nick, I actually found that it wasn't a difference in running the emulator vs device, it was actually the email account I set up. Turns out the email link only launches my app if it's from my gmail account and not my yahoo or work account I set up on the device. (note: this is all using the native android email app).

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing on both emulator and physical devices using an app that handles a custom scheme. My test devices are running 2.2 and 2.3, and my application isn't signed. Double check the components of the intent filter and the setup for your tests on the emulator and the device.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a quick response. Thanks for confirming that the app does not have to be signed for this feature to work. I actually found this.. On my device I'm using the native email client and I set up two accounts, one of them being my gmail account. The custom email link from my gmail actually launches my app correctly, however the link from my other email accounts I've set up does not work.